# USB port noise and how to deal with it, or avoid it?

Tags: usb, audio, microphone, electret, sound-card

I am designing and testing a DIY microphone. The idea is to amplify an electret mic signal before sending it to a PC's sound card to avoid using digital gain.

The circuit just uses 2 opamp OPA2134PA, 2-opamp as amplifier. All the capacitors are film type, and all of the resistors are metal film, 1%.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2nfF8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In a first attempt I powered it from the PC's USB port. As expectedpect, I got a ton of background noise; it sounds like a high-pitch machine. I tried many approaches like

- CLC pi network (1uf, 100mH, 1uF)
- CRC (1uF 10ohm 1 uF)
- Add 10uF electrolite and 0.1uF film to bypass (combined with each approach)

Which did reduce noise but did not eliminate the noise.

I tried another approach by using LM1117 3.3V LDO regulator (with 0.1uF film cap for bypass) for mic (the op-amp needs at least 4.5V to work) the result is ... well, the high pitch noise transforms to white noise like no-signal TV which interecting scenario how the noise characteristic transformed.

By the way, my USB mic also has background white noise. I think that this is farthest I can go.

Now I throw all solutions away and just use a 9V battery to power the circuit and all the problems go away with it.

Now the story ends but I am still looking for a battery-less solution because the mic is stationary and I don't want to worry about changing batteries. I have some solution in mind:

1. Fix the USB noise using using power isolation somehow (not sure it will work);
2. Use a boost convertor to boost the USB voltage to 12V (maybe a higher voltage can reduce effect of noise ripple);
3. Use a 12V external adaptor; not sure if a 2.5mm wall adaptor will suitable for this application;
4. Use a DIY supply; this is the difficult way I want to avoid.

What should it be?

Comment: You're only focussing on the supply for the opamps, that's good and what also helps is the supply rejection of the opamps. So there's only so much you can achieve, which is what you experience. The other part is a **clean signal** so careful routing and connectiong of the ground connection. If some of the supply current flows through your signal ground then that will be added to your output signal. Your first step might be to look at a star ground connection: https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/staying-well-grounded.html

Comment: Post a picture of your circuit with the linear regulator. White noise sounds like some kind of grounding or wiring problem. That regulator should have reduced your overall supply noise roughly 1000x.

Answer (score 1):

I will explain the fundamental part of noise and grounding only, but not the rest of your goals. How you accomplish it depends on the detail of your implementation and interpretation.

Give a low impedance between the mic - audio input, especially to the ground, thus the GND is referenced to the audio input circuitry GND. Shield the wire with this ground, unless your system shield/chassis ground is properly designed.

Create as high impedance as possible (can be isolated for the max effect) between the USB and the mic circuitry. That is possible, if the audio input uses system ground, and since the mic circuitry does not need to drive high current to the audio card.. unless.. need to watch the impedance and bias. Otherwise, it is simpler to isolate the power (battery or isolating switch mode pwr).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4YGJX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: with C1 more like 1000uF than 10uF...